# p2p video conference

Tags: video, chat, p2p

I have developed a peer to peer wpf application and in it I am just broadcasting my video to other peers, but I also want to see their video at the same time. Currently I do not know how to pass my video stream to other peer's machine so that they can process it on their own. I want it to be p2p video conferencing. I want that one peer should be sending its video to other peers and simultaneously it is receiving videos from other peers.

What approach should I use?

Threads to handle multiple clients request at same time?

Answer (score 0):

It seems very plausible that you would have one thread (or more) processing your own video for transmission to the other participants in the conference, while having one thread handling the video input from each of the other participants for display to your own screen, plus any stray threads for controlling the layout, etc. (So, if there are N people in the conference, there'd be 1 transmission thread, N-1 display threads, and a controller thread, plus sundry others as seems most appropriate.)

You might have one video feed at a larger size than the others, for example, and the controller thread would be used to allow you to select which is the primary (enlarged) video feed at any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, investigate [NIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) and libraries built on top of NIO (such as Netty for example) to limit the usage of threads. These can handle multiple connections much more efficiently than with multiple threads.